# QGIS version update makes project slow

Tags: qgis, update

I have updated from version 2.6 to 2.12. I have opened and saved my project in the newer version. Now it runs really slowly. For example every time I zoom in or out or pan the map I have to wait 20-30 seconds while it redraws everything. A colleague has had a similar problem in the past upgrading 1.8 to 2.2 (or something like)

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Frudd! Have you set the **Rendering behavior** in _Settings > Options > Rendering_? You can increase the number of CPU cores used and enable cache rendering to speed up redrawing.

Comment: Thanks, I have done those things and it hasn't made any appreciable difference

Comment: How fast was the redraw before? What kind of dataproviders are involved? Do you have any plugins installed / enabled?

Comment: It used to be fairly instantaneous. Current task involved drawing polygons from scanned images and I need to be able to switch between two georeferenced images to compare them. Now it itkes so long to redraw everything that I forget what I was looking at. I dont think there are any plugins but I didnt install it.

Comment: I have found that if I store the files locally rather than on the office network everything runs as fast as I am used to...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried re-building your project?  Low tech solution I know but often I find this the quickest most effective solution.